# Configurar proxy Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ionic2

Al ejecutar

```
ionic start Aplication_mobile blank
```

sale error al descargar el template

```
Fetching app base (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app base/archive/master.tar.gz)
✖ Downloading - failed!
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.113:443
```

He configurado npm con el proxy y no funciona. También he creado una variable del sistema:

```
PROXY=http://proxy:8081
```

y sigue sin funcionar.

Version de ionic: 3.1.2

Comment: Verifica que sea la última versión del CLI `npm view ionic@latest version`. También verifica manualmente que la url de la descarga se encuentre bien. Verifica algún firewall que bloquee a github.

Comment: node como angular, ionic y cordova están recién instalados a la última versión :'( @x4mp73r

Comment: Verifica lo último que te dije, que no este bloqueado github ya sea en el firewall. intenta descargarlo manualmente para ver que pasa.

Comment: Al copiar la url al navegador la descarga perfectamente también al quitar el proxy y salir directamente a internet también funciona. El problema es que no puedo estar sin proxy mucho tiempo. Gracias @x4mp73r

Comment: Estoy con el mismo problema, mismas caracteristicas, ionic 3.2.0 todo funciona detras de proxy correctamente, excepto con ionic. Has encontrado alguna solucion @JoseYeste

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado la solución.

El problema es que si configuras el proxy en npm ionic no lo hereda hay que cambiarlo en el archivo de configuración. 
Se encuentra en C:\Users\usuario\.ionic\config.json
Y añadimos el proxy

```
"proxies": [
 {
  "proxyUrl": "http://proxy:8081"
 }
]
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por compartir la solución!

Comment: Perdon, no habia leido esta solucion. Voy a probar

Comment: la información la saqué de aqui @Enrique  https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución viable y que probe y funcionó fue la siguiente:
en la consola ejecutas el siguiente comando:

```
ionic config set -g proxy http://proxy.example.com:8888
```

y así funciona correctamente también saludos